# Calculating the contraction of a field operator and a creation operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform, commutator

In Folland's *Quantum Field Theory* (section 6.4) he considers a field:

$$\phi_\pi = \sum_\tau \int f(\textbf{q})\big[u(\textbf{q}, \tau, \pi)a(\textbf{q}, \tau, \pi) e^{-iq_\mu x^\mu} +  v(\textbf{q}, \tau, \overline{\pi})a^\dagger(\textbf{q}, \tau, \overline{\pi}) e^{iq_\mu x^\mu}\big] \frac{d^3\textbf{q}}{(2\pi)^3}$$
where $\overline{\pi}$ is the antiparticle of $\pi$ and $f(\textbf{q})$ contains all scalar factors such as $\sqrt{2\omega_p}$. For convenience, I split the annihilation and creation parts of $\phi_\pi$ as $\phi_\pi^a$ and $\phi_\pi^c$, respectively. Truthfully I am not sure what $u$ and $v$ represent above, but I'm guessing they're some kind of generalized coefficients.

I wish to compute
$$\overbrace{\phi_\pi(x)a^\dagger(\textbf{p}, \sigma, \pi')}$$
which is the contraction between the field and a creation operator which creates a particle of species $\pi'$ with momentum $\textbf{p}$ and spin $\sigma$.

Since both quantities are time independent we have that
$$\overbrace{\phi_\pi(x)a^\dagger(\textbf{p}, \sigma, \pi')} = [\phi_\pi^a, a^\dagger] = \sum_\tau \int f(\textbf{q})u(\textbf{q}, \tau, \pi)a(\textbf{q}, \tau, \pi) a^\dagger(\textbf{p}, \sigma, \pi')e^{-iq_\mu x^\mu}\frac{d^3\textbf{q}}{(2\pi)^3} \tag{1}.$$

Using the canonical commutation relation
$$[a(\textbf{q}), a^\dagger(\textbf{p})] = \delta(\textbf{q} - \textbf{p})$$
we may rewrite (1) to be
$$\sum_\tau \int f(\textbf{q})u(\textbf{q}, \tau, \pi) e^{-iq_\mu x^\mu}\delta(\textbf{q} - \textbf{p})\frac{d^3\textbf{q}}{(2\pi)^3} = \sum_\tau f(\textbf{p})u(\textbf{p}, \tau, \pi)e^{-ip_\mu x^\mu}.$$

And so I have calculated that
$$\overbrace{\phi_\pi(x)a^\dagger(\textbf{p}, \sigma, \pi')} = \sum_\tau f(\textbf{p})u(\textbf{p}, \tau, \pi)e^{-ip_\mu x^\mu}.$$

However, this is incorrect as Folland says this quantity should instead be
$$\overbrace{\phi_\pi(x)a^\dagger(\textbf{p}, \sigma, \pi')} = f(\textbf{p})u(\textbf{p}, \sigma, \pi)e^{-ip_\mu x^\mu}\delta_{\pi \pi'}. \tag{2}$$

How did he get rid of the summation, the second parameter of $u$ to be $\sigma$ instead of $\tau$, and why is there an extra $\delta$ function at the end?

He also says that this computation was essentially done earlier in the book when he showed that
$$\langle 0 | \phi(t,\textbf{x})a^\dagger(\textbf{p}) | 0 \rangle = \frac{e^{ip_\mu x^\mu}}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}. \tag{3}$$
By a corrollary of Wick's theorem the above should be equal to a sum of contractions, which I assume in this case must be just
$$\overbrace{\phi_\pi(x)a^\dagger(\textbf{p}, \sigma, \pi')}.$$
If so, why has the sign in the exponential changed from (2) to (3)? Does (3) instead correspond to the calculation
$$\overbrace{a(\textbf{p}, \sigma, \pi')\phi_\pi(x)}$$
where $a$ is an annihilation operator?

Comment: I think it boils down to your CCR not being complete. Without having all the context, I think it probably should be something like $[a(p, \sigma, \pi), a^\dagger(q, \tau, \pi')] = \delta(p-q) \delta_{\sigma, \tau} \delta_{\pi, \pi'}$ (it's not 100% clear to me what system you are studying, so I'll just note that for fermions you would have an anticommutation relation instead of a commutation relation). With that change, the sum over $\tau$ will kill the $\delta_{\sigma, \tau}$, and you'll have an overall factor $\delta_{\pi,\pi'}$.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you, that would make sense. Do you know why the sign of the exponential is different from (2) to (3)?